# How can I access or get data(bit stream) in PCI configuration register(space) in Windows platform

Tags: python, c++, c, configuration, pci-e

I need to read data in PCI configuration register. PCI configuraion registers are allocated in memory because PCI architecture is memory mapped I/O. So, I want to read the data in configuration register or space in Windows OS. How can I get this data?

I already installed the Windows Driver developer kit. I followed the guidance in MSDN. But, I failed to load the header file or DDK file in Visual Studio 2019. If the trial that I have done is correct, how can I solve the error "cannot open source file "wdm.h""? Or the method that I have tried, what is the method to get PCI configuration register(space) data in Windows OS?
Please recommend.

> Cannot open source file "wdm.h"

I installed the Windows Driver Kit following the guidance in MSDN. But the error is still present. Would I add the include file directory to a solution property or a configuration variable to system?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Also, since the compiler can't find the *wdm.h* header your problem is more fundamental than how to use the APIs defined in that header.

Comment: The python tag dosen't have enough explain.Actually I also try to get the data in PCI configuration register by Python. So Is there any proper API made by Python to get PCI configuration register? Or How Can I fix the problem that I explain about window driver develop kit in Visual Studio?